# Arduino yield in Atmel Studio

Tags: c++, arduino, arduino-esp8266, atmelstudio

I'm trying to write code for Arduino in Atmel Studio 7. To keep it similar to Arduino IDE, I'm trying to adapt its libs.

But I got already blocked by `delay()`, which uses `yield()`. Yield does not seem to be implemented anywhere. So my compiler says *"undefined reference to yield"*.

I don't understand how the Arduino IDE handles that? What can I do to use `yield()` in Atmel Studio?

Here's my try:

```
#ifndef F_CPU
#define F_CPU 16000000UL
#endif
#include <util/delay.h>
#include <avr/io.h>

#include <Arduino.h>
#include <wiring.c>

int main(void) {
  DDRB = (1 << DDB5);
  while(1) {
    PORTB = (1 << DDB5);
    delay(1000);
    PORTB = (0 << DDB5);
    delay(1000);
  }
}
```

Comment: I think `yield()` is a part of `scheduler`... Add `scheduler.h` from the Arduino libraries to your project.

Comment: delays should be avoided at any cost

Comment: And what is the point to use silly Arduino stuff if you have started to use bare registers. Keep following this way and forget about arduino

Comment: Another remark - do not define F_CPU in your code. Do this in the project properties. It will help you to avoid stupid mistakes like different values in different files.

Comment: Thanks, especially for the F_CPU hint,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although delays, as the commenters suggest, are usually to be avoided, most of us who program bare metal Atmel chips start off with the blinking LED program.  It's the "Hello World" of bare-metal embedded programming.  A delay is fine for this.

If you will look in you `util/delay.h` though, you will see functions that are especially written for your chip.  Use those instead and do not link in the Arduino versions.  You will find a `_delay_ms()` and `_delay_us()` functions which are perfect for this first-steps type of program.

Comment: Ah thanks. I will try delay_ms(). On the end I want to control a LED panel witch must not be so fast ... must then change colors etc in a time. So a kind of timing must be implemented. Maybe I can somehow measure time periods during loops and trigger a change light event then. In pc application it is a must to never run a loop but work with events. So can I assume in microprocessor applications I can do a loop with no hassle or do I then block sensors etc?

Answer (score 2):

Here's how it's implemented in the Arduino AVR Boards core:
https://github.com/arduino/Arduino/blob/1.8.3/hardware/arduino/avr/cores/arduino/hooks.c#L19-L31

```
void yield(void) __attribute__ ((weak, alias("__empty")));
```

As the comments in that file explain:

> Empty yield() hook.
>   This function is intended to be used by library writers to build libraries or sketches that supports cooperative threads. Its defined as a weak symbol and it can be redefined to implement a real cooperative scheduler.

So you can define `yield()` in your own code if you like. Otherwise the empty definition will prevent the undefined reference error you encountered.

Of course it's better to write proper non-blocking code rather than using this `yield()` workaround but you asked how the Arduino IDE handles it and so there you have it.

Comment: I found that as well, but to be honest, I still don't understand? Somehow it means, that it does nothing, but otherwise arduino waits a time. How does it come alive?

Comment: In `delay()`: https://github.com/arduino/Arduino/blob/1.8.3/hardware/arduino/avr/cores/arduino/wiring.c#L106-L117 `yield()` is called repeatedly from the `while()` loop. This means that you can add a definition of `yield()` in your code and the contents will not be blocked by use of the `delay()` function. But most users won't have any use for this function and so won't define `yield()` in their code. The weak empty `yield()` definition in the core is necessary so that `yield()` will always be defined. If the user defines their own `yield()` then it will override the weak definition.

Answer (score 0):

Thank for your help. So I created a solution with class style:

```
#include "Blink.h"

#include <util/delay.h>
#include "Arduino.h"

#define boardLedOn PORTB  |= (1 << DDB5);
#define boardLedOff PORTB &= ~(1 << DDB5); // inverse bits

#define delay(ms) _delay_ms(ms);

Blink::Blink(){
};

void Blink::run(){

    boardLedOn;

    delay(1000);

    boardLedOff;

    delay(1000);

}
```

Caller:

```
#include <avr/io.h>
#include <Arduino.h>
#include <Blink.h>

int main(void)
{


    Blink blink;

    while(1)
    {       
        blink.run();        
    }
}
```

header file:

```
#ifndef BLINK_H
#define BLINK_H

class Blink{

  public: 

    Blink();
    void run();

};

#endif
```